InvalidOperationException in ASP.NET Core MVC using Entity Framework Core and ASP.NET Core Identity
I am creating an ASP.NET Core MVC project, using Entity Framework Core and ASP.NET Core Identity. After applying all changes to my edit (using CRUD) I get this error message on the following line:
var existingProduct = _context.Products.Find(id);


System.InvalidOperationException: 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.'

Here is the code of the edit function in ProductsController:
[HttpPost]
[Route("edit/{id}")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Edit(int id, Product model)
{
    using (var _context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var existingProduct = _context.Products.Find(id);

        if (existingProduct == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            existingProduct.Name = model.Name;
            existingProduct.Stock = model.Stock;
            existingProduct.Price = model.Price;
            existingProduct.ImageUrl = model.ImageUrl;

            _context.SaveChanges();

            return Redirect("/");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Products");
    }
}

Now here is my ApplicationDbContext file:
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
        public ApplicationDbContext()
        {
        }
        

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

And finally my Startup.cs:
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(   
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

    services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}

Since I'm sure you noticed I have an empty constructor, here is why I actually have it. Upon not having this empty constructor I get this error message:

Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'options' of 'ApplicationDbContext.ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions)'

The error is given on the lines with calling ApplicationDbContext
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("edit/{id}")]
    public IActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        using (var _context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            {
                var product = this._context.Products.Find(id);
                if (product == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                return View(product);
            }
        }

[HttpPost]
[Route("edit/{id}")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Edit(int id, Product model)
{
    using (var _context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
         var existingProduct = _context.Products.Find(id);

         if (existingProduct == null)
         {
             return NotFound();
         }

         if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
         {
             existingProduct.Name = model.Name;
             existingProduct.Stock = model.Stock;
             existingProduct.Price = model.Price;
             existingProduct.ImageUrl = model.ImageUrl;
             _context.SaveChanges();

             return Redirect("/");
         }
         return RedirectToAction("Index", "Products");
     }
}


I seem to have found a solution or at least a temporary one. In my Edit.cshtml file I added this bit:
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Products", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
    <!-- Form fields here -->
}

I believe the issue was in the AntiForgeryToken. Although if anyone else finds a better solution, or one that could potentially be the right one, I would really appreciate it!
